# voice call with agora and firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, agora.io

I'm trying to implement voice call functions in my app using agora and firebase where the user can make one to one calls but here in this join function I pass the channel name which is the same for both users in firebase
but I don't know what to pass in the optionalUid which uid is this? and the token in agora require a channel name to generate one but I don't want to type a specific channel name in the console what should I do?

```
  _joinChannel() async {
await Permission.microphone.request();
await _engine
    .joinChannel(null, widget.call.channelName!, null,
    optionalUid)
    .catchError((onError) {
  print('error ${onError.toString()}');
});}
```

Comment: I used `optionalUid=0` and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If the `optionalUid` is not set, or set to `0` it will automatically create one for you.

You can read about it more here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/flutter/v4.0.5/agora_rtc_engine/RtcEngine/joinChannel.html